# Many-to-Many Link Table Foreign Key Modeling in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, referential-integrity

I have the following two tables in SQLite:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Link` (
    `link_id`   integer NOT NULL,
    `part_id`   integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `link_pk` PRIMARY KEY(`link_id`,`part_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `Main` (
    `main_id`   integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `link_id`   integer NOT NULL REFERENCES `Link`(`link_id`)
);
INSERT INTO `Link` (link_id, part_id) VALUES (1,10);
INSERT INTO `Link` (link_id, part_id) VALUES (1,11);
INSERT INTO `Link` (link_id, part_id) VALUES (1,12);
INSERT INTO `Link` (link_id, part_id) VALUES (2,15);

INSERT INTO `Main` (main_id, link_id) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO `Main` (main_id, link_id) VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO `Main` (main_id, link_id) VALUES (3,2);
```

Many `Main` rows may reference the same link id, and many `Link` rows may have the same link id, such that `select * from Main natural join Link where main_id=1` will return N rows, and `select * from Main where link_id=1` will return K rows. The link id is important, and the original data each main has 1 link id, and each link has N part ids.

Using the schemas above, I am unable to insert any rows in `Main` due to the foreign key constraint (`foreign key mismatch - "Main" referencing "Link":  INSERT INTO Main (main_id, link_id) VALUES (1,1);`), presumably because of [the composite key requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542427). I can get this to work by removing the foreign key constraint, but then I am obviously missing a constraint. Reversing the direction of the key wouldn't work either since, as stated above, it's a Many-to-Many relationship. Is there a way to properly model this in SQLite with a constraint that at least one row exists in `Link` for each `link_id` in `Main`?

Comment: What kind of rows are you not able to insert? The three rows in the sample can be inserted just OK.

Comment: You should reconsider your design. `link_id` and `part_id` should be the primary keys in 2 different tables and your current table `Link` should be the junction  table of these tables. Then you can have `Main`'s `link_id` to reference the 1st table's `link_id`.

Comment: @choroba running the code currently gives me: `foreign key mismatch - "Main" referencing "Link":  INSERT INTO Main (main_id, link_id) VALUES (1,1);`

Comment: @forpas do you want to expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would propose a different design.

Each of the 2 entities `link_id` and `part_id` should be the primary key in 2 tables, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Links (
    link_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    link_description TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Parts (
    part_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    part_description TEXT
);
```

Then, create the junction table of the above tables (like your current `Link` table):

```
CREATE TABLE Links_Parts (
    link_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Links(link_id),
    part_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Parts(part_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(link_id, part_id)
);
```

and the table `Main`:

```
CREATE TABLE Main (
    main_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    link_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Links(link_id)
);
```

All the relations are there and you have referential integrity guaranteed if you set foreign key support:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e3547857bc395b733f8ded470c895db4).

Comment: Given that links have no description or other attributes, it's so weird having a table with just one column. However, this doesn't enforce links having at least one part. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @byteit101 Usually all entities like a *link* or a *part* have a description of some kind. Anyway, if it is not needed then you can have a table with only 1 column. But, the constraint that every link should have at least one part can't be enforced by sql only. In your application code you should make sure that you insert a new row in `Links` only if you have a pair of the new inserted link and part to insert in `Links_Parts` as a 2nd step. Also you may need triggers to catch orphaned links after updates or deletes in `Links_Parts`.